# Question regarding Kronecker delta

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

Given that, $\frac{\partial A^\mu}{\partial A^\nu} = \delta^\mu _\nu$.

How to reach $\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial A_\nu} = \delta_\mu ^\nu$ ?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial A_\nu}=\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial A^\rho}\frac{\partial A^\rho}{\partial A^\sigma}\frac{\partial A^\sigma}{\partial A_\nu}=g_{\mu\rho}\delta^\rho_\sigma g^{\sigma\nu}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial A_\nu} 
= g_{\mu \rho} g^{\nu \sigma} \frac{\partial A^\rho}{\partial A^\sigma} = g_{\mu \rho} g^{\nu \sigma} \delta^\rho_\sigma = g_{\mu \rho} g^{\nu \rho} = \delta_\mu^\nu$$

where $g$ is the metric you are using, and I use the usual notation in which $\frac{\partial}{\partial A^\mu} \equiv \partial_\mu$ transforms as a covariant quantity (indices lowered) and $\frac{\partial}{\partial A_\mu} \equiv \partial^\mu \equiv g^{\mu \rho} \partial_\rho $